# Is it possible to refer our old domain name in Google search results if someone search my new domain name?

Tags: seo, domains, google-search, search-results

We moved our site to a new domain. Is it possible that the results that appear when someone Google our previous name, also appear when someone Google our new name?

Comment: You should redirect user to new domain when user enter/search your old domain.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a step by step guide on what to do when migrating your website:

1. **301 redirect your website:** Make sure all of your old domain urls redirect to their *representative* url on your new website.[1]
2. **Index your 301 redirected website:** Fire up Google webmaster for you old domain and perform `Fetch as Google` in order to emulate Google displaying the search engine result page.

This step is crucial in quickly getting your old brand name's website removed from search and showing the new website (mostly) in it's stead.

Because you have 301 redirected your previous domain, Google should be intelligent enough to transfer the contextual brand information to your new brand URL and it should show your new URL.

Expect some migration issues for indexing during this period; you could manually fetch **every** url on your old domain to "speed" up the process but that would be cumbersome for larger websites.

Always monitor `site:olddomain.com`to check if pages are still indexed and be sure to compare this to your new website.

`site:olddomain.com | site:newdomain.com`should only display results from your new domain on the first page.

**However** if your brand name has generic terms it is possible that you will be out ranked for your old brand name term. This gets into the whole scope of Online Reputation Management as a service where your will have to rank your domain for your old brand name terms.

Comment: One slight correction. The Fetch as Google is not a required step nor do I really recommend it. It certainly does not do any harm of course. I recommend reserving the Fetch as Google for highly critical issues and not natural/normal changes. The 301 redirect will help users just fine and it will be a matter of just 1-2 days generally (depending upon site freshness) for Google to find the 301 redirect. Google will sample the site and see the blanket 301 and re-index the entire site very quickly. Doing a Fetch as Google really does not speed things up. It can actually slow things down sometimes.